# SOAPUI:- Comparing two assertions of different test cases

Tags: soapui

I have added Assertion in two different test steps.
Each assertion is giving me count of nodes.

For Example:-

```
Assertion 1:- Give count of nodes from JDBC test step
Assertion 2:- Give count of nodes from JSON response test step
```

How can i compare this two assertions?

Comment: What do you mean "compare this two assertions"? If both assertions fail they are equal, and test passes?

Comment: No i mean both assertions are giving count of node and i want to match both assertions. If both assertions are equal then test pass else fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `groovy script` including the assertions. If I understand right, you may redesign the tests into a single case so that there would not be any dependency on other test, i.e., each an every test should be independent.

Assuming the case - A test case with below steps

1. step1 - is of type Jdbc Test Step
2. step2 - is of type Rest Test Step
3. step3 - is of type Groovy Script Test Step

Here is the sudo code that goes in step3:

- Get the response of step1 and do whatever process you wanted to do on that response. Since you mentioned node count, have the node count in a variable, say `jdbcNodeCount`.
- Similarly, do the same thing for step2 and have the node count in an another variable, say `jsonNodeCount`.
- It can be easily compared both the variables.

How to get the response of other steps from with in groovy step? Here you go:

```groovy
//You may rename step1, step2 as needed to your environment

//initializing count variables
def jdbcNodeCount = 0
def jsonNodeCount = 0
//Get step1 response
def jdbcResponse = context.expand('${step1#Response}')
log.info jdbcResponse
//process jdbcResponse and assign jdbcNodeCount, add needed steps 

//also add additional the assertions required for jdbcResponse here, so that you would not need Assertion 1 that you had already

//Similarly get step2 response
def jsonResponse = context.expand('${step2#Response}')
log.info jsonResponse
//process jsonResponse and assign jsonNodeCount, add needed steps

//also add additional the assertions required for jsonResponse here, so that you would not need Assertion 2 that you had already

//compare now
assert jsonNodeCount == jdbcNodeCount, "Node counts are not matching"
```